# Rails + Testing: How to change DatabaseCleaner:strategy for only 1 specific test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to use `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation` for one of my cucumber tests. I heard it's better to use transaction for performance, so I want to leave the rest my tests alone with `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction`. How would I do this on the fly? I tried doing this with a hook, but it didn't work:

```
Before('@sphinx') do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
end

After('@sphinx') do
  Book.connection.execute "TRUNCATE TABLE `books`"
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {:except => %w[sphinx]}

DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction, {:only => %w[sphinx]}
```